# Command not found in child process when using "pexpect"

Tags: python-3.x, process, pexpect

I am using python3.9 with library "pexpect", and I am trying to run some commands in a child process (and then wait for a specific result).
The problem is that my child process has different $PATH than the parent, and hence it cannot find some commands that I want to use.
My code looks like this:

```
child = pexpect.spawn(f"foo 1 2", timeout=None)
child.expect(f"foo command ran successfully")
```

I can run "foo" command in the parent process, but in the child process I get "command not found".
Is there a way to solve this? I think I need to make sure the child process has the same $PATH value, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use `env` to set the environment variables in your child process. Something like:

```py
import subprocess

# you could use "foo" instead of "env", but this is more robust
cmd = ["env", "foo", "1", "2"]
subprocess.run(cmd, check=True)
```

Comment: But how can I monitor the response that way?
Maybe I should have mentioned that my child process runs forever.

Answer (score 0):

I think that did the trick:

```py
pexpect.spawn(f"foo 1 2", env=dict(os.environ), timeout=None)
```